# Accessing shell variable in awk but not interpreted

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am very new to awk programming ...

Here is my code where I am trying to access shell variable `count` in awk

```
ivlen=`cat record.txt | awk -F " " '{printf "%s",$10}'`
echo $ivlen

count=` expr $ivlen / 2 `
echo $count

echo "\nInitialization Vector : (Value) "

  // This one needs attention
```

**Edit :**

```
iv=`awk -v count=$count 'BEGIN {RS=" ";ORS=" ";}     
           {if (NR > 4 && NR < count+4 )print $0}' esp_payload.txt`
echo $iv
```

**Input:**

```
  $cat esp_payload.txt
  0000 5FB4 0000 0041
  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
  0000 0000 0000 0000 5361 6C74 6564 5F5F
  D678 E0DA A075 5361 02B4 6273 D970 2F72
```

**Output:(required)** (I want those `0000` strings `12 in number`)

```
 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
  // this is what I want not what is displayed
```

**output : (displayed on screen)**

```
 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 5361
```

Now what is going wrong ?? why one `0000` not printed and why `5361` printed out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is counting `0041\n0000` as a single record because it has no space character in it. You're also getting `0000\n0000` as a single field in your output, but you can't tell because you `echo $iv` instead of `echo "$iv"`

Change `RS=" "` to `RS="[ \n]"`.

Comment: RS=" " is special-cased, to use any span of whitespace as a separator (and omit leading and trailing whitespace). POSIX requires that spaces and tabs be included as whitespace for these purposes, but doesn't require that `\n` be included too. Some implementations of awk (at least gawk and BusyBox) do include `\n`; others (FreeBSD's nawk) don't.

Comment: Sorry, what I said is true of FS not RS. Don't know what my brain was doing then.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables to `awk` by using `-v` and your script can be simplified a bit, because `{print $0}` is the default action:

```
iv=`awk -v count="$count" 'BEGIN { RS=" "; ORS=" " } 
        (NR > 4 && NR < count)' esp_payload.txt`
```

Comment: Please see my edit .. may be I am doing something conceptually wrong ...as I hav specified I am new so did not knew about this default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is in single quotes, bash doesn't substitue variables in single quoted strings.

The cleanest way to pass parameters to awk: `awk 'script.....' count=$count`.

Comment: but I need to access the variable in between the script if I would go as you suggested what would I substitute at the place where it is required the script